# Multiple File upload with Shift + select all functionality

Tags: select, file-upload

Hi I have used the AJAX solution proferred by Ramani Sandeep in his blog

http://ramanisandeep.net/2009/10/28/multiple-file-upload-using-jquery/#comment-1847

This works excellently!

However, I need something that can allow the user click on browse button ONCE, select all the files either by holding Ctrl down and selecting OR by pressing Shift + select first and Last file. Now I think this is possible. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
I used it many times.
Like other solutions, file content is sended by flash wich allows to watch progress and selet multiple files.
You can customize max queue size etc. by JavaScript
You can also set additional variables, like PHPSESSID be sure that upload handled by backend from Flash se properly logged user.

I can customize queue display (it's html+css) and button label from JS.